# АОП в Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, aop

Здравствуйте, возник проблемы с использованием АОП в Java. Никак не могу понять, почему не работает логгирование, уже все перепробовал... Вот например у меня есть сервис которые выполняем какое-либо действие с entity через repostirory, и хотелось ыб логировтаь упешное и неуспешное выполнение действий, вот код, который по каким-то непонятным мне причинам нек работает:

#### Service

```
@Service
public class QuestionsServiceImpl implements QuestionsService {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    public boolean removeQuestion(String titleQuestion) {
        Question question = questionRepository.findByTitle(titleQuestion);
        if(question != null){
            questionRepository.deleteByTitle(titleQuestion);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Другие действия

}
```

#### Aspect

```
@Log4j
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingQuestionService {

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* ru.testingsystem.data.service.QuestionsService.removeQuestion(title))",
                    returning= "resultDeleting", argNames = "resultDeleting, title")
    public void logRemovingQuestion(boolean resultDeleting, String title){
        if (resultDeleting){
            log.debug("Question [" + title + "] was deleted.");
        } else {
            log.debug("Question [" + title + "] wasn't deleted. This Question not found.");
        }
    }

    // Логирование других дейтсвий

}
```

Может кто-нибудь подскажет в чем проблема... То уже и не знаю что делать самому.

Comment: В pointcut в блоке execution, вроде, вместо title надо использовать тип, в вашем случае String.

Answer (score 2):

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* ru.testingsystem.data.service.QuestionsService.removeQuestion(..)) && args(title)",
                returning= "resultDeleting", argNames = "resultDeleting, title")
```

Или (с типизацией):

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(boolean ru.testingsystem.data.service.QuestionsService.removeQuestion(String)) && args(title)",
                returning= "resultDeleting", argNames = "resultDeleting, title")
```

Comment: К сожалению, тоже не работает... Intelij IDEA все отображает корректно, что используется аспект, но толку ноль.

Comment: Я у себя локально на небольшом примере проверил. Возможно, у вас проблемы с конфигами - как подключаете?

Comment: Использую maven для подключения библиотек(spring-aop и aspectj) ну и заданию component scan  для аспекта

Comment: бин аспекта создается? при вызове логгируемого метода в консоли пусто? метод `removeQuestion(String)` есть в `QuestionsService` (спрашиваю т.к. у вас `@Override` отсутствует)?

Comment: Конечно есть, в консоли пусто, в каком плане без аспекта создается?

Comment: добавьте в класс аспекта конструктор или (postConstruct метод) и проверьте вызывается ли он